# JavaScript: import npm packages

Tags: javascript, npm

I am not very familiar with javascript modules. I am starting to work on a project and for that I needed a library from npm.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/random-color-pair

Therefore, as I ran `npm i random-color-pair`

This made a "node modules" named folder which contained the files of the package. I tried several ways to import that in my javascript but am not able to find a way to do so.

File Structure:
[image: File Structure]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="main.js" type="module">
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have already tried the following (none of them work):

```
import getColorPair from "random-color-pair";
import getColorPair from "node_modules/random-color-pair";
import getColorPair from "./node_modules/random-color-pair";
import "./node_modules/random-color-pair";
import getColorPair from "./node_modules/random-color-pair/index";
import "./node_modules/random-color-pair/index";
```

Comment: It looks like you're not using a bundler like webpack, parcel, etc, is that correct?

Comment: This won't work right off the bat, you will need a bundler like webpack or parcel to compile/combine the code in the package with your code. Should I post an answer regarding this? I'd recommend using parcel because it is super easy to setup

Comment: https://github.com/benrosen/random-color-pair/blob/main/index.js does not use ESM.

Comment: So where can I learn more about bundlers?

Comment: Google is your friend here. Normally I'd go to the bundler's website. Some bundlers include Webpack, Parcel, Rollup, Browserify, FuseBox, Brunch, and more

Comment: @Akash Yes you should put that as an answer. Thanks for helping everyone.

Comment: @MeetShah will do that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work right off the bat, you will need a bundler like webpack or parcel to compile/combine the code in the package with your code. I'll show you how to use and configure parcel because that is the easiest.

Start by installing the bundler:

```
npm install parcel-bundler -D
```

Update the `scripts` section in the `package.json`

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "parcel ./index.html",
    "build": "parcel build ./index.html"
  }
}
```

Now you can install any module from npm:

```
npm i <module_name>
```

And import it in your `main.js` file like so:

```
import module_name as 'module_name';
```

To start up your dev server(which will automatically change when you update your code) run this:

```
npm run dev
```

And for the production bundle(which can be uploaded to hosting platforms):

```
npm run build
```

I hope this was useful and let me know if it worked for you!

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer as correct and upvote it if it helped you!

Answer (score 1):

`random-color-pair` internally use this library  : [randomcolor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/randomcolor).

You should install this directly like like this : npm i randomcolor

And import it like this :

### HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="node_modules/randomcolor/randomColor.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### JS (main.js) :

```
function getColorPair() {
  const isForegroundDark = Math.random() < 0.5
  const foregroundColor = randomColor({
    luminosity: isForegroundDark ? 'dark' : 'light'
  })
  const backgroundColor = randomColor({
    luminosity: isForegroundDark ? 'light' : 'dark'
  })
  return [foregroundColor, backgroundColor]
}

var color = getColorPair();
console.log("color", color);
```

Do not need to import anything in JS file.